# getting the name of a typedef in C?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, typedef, void

I am writing a big code where I have to typedef a lot of structs , and then using void pointers to variables of these structs , for example :

```
typedef struct {
    int age;
    double height;
}human_t;
```

and then I will declare and initialize a variable of type:"human_t"

```
human_t peter = {
    21,
    1.95 };
```

then I will make a void pointer to peter :

```
void* ptr = &peter;
```

what I later need is to know that "ptr" is a pointer to variable of type "human_t". How can I do this ? is there some kind of a predefined method in C ? sorry for my ignorance :) still a beginner .

Comment: You cannot do this unless you store this information somewhere yourself. As a rule, there are no hidden things in C.  If you have a `void*`, that's *all* you have.

Comment: Not too relevant but note that `_t` suffix is reserved for posix types

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that is impossible "out of the box".

It would require run-time type information to be somehow associated with the pointer, and that simply does not exist. A `void` pointer is a memory address, and nothing more.

You can, of course, as with many things that exist in higher-level languages, implement it yourself.

For this case, you can require that each supported `struct` begins with an `enum` that specifies its type. You can then convert the pointer to struct into a pointer to that enum, read its value, and then know which type you're dealing with:

```
typedef enum {
  ObjectType_Human,
  ObjectType_Alien,
  ObjectType_Predator,
  ObjectType_Smurf,
} ObjectType;

typedef struct {
  ObjectType type;
  int age;
  char name[32];
} human;
```

Then you can do:

```
void print_name(const void *obj)
{
  const ObjectType *tp = obj; /* No cast required! */
  switch(*tp)
  {
  case ObjectType_Human:
    printf("the human is called %s\n", ((human *) obj)->name);
    break;
  /* and so on ... */
  }
}
```

You could also, for instance, put the type information in a map, hashed on the pointer value.

There are many approaches; you're going to have to analyze and pick the best one for your particular application.

Answer (score 2):

Alas this is not easy to implement in C.

One approach is to standardise your structures so that the first element is a type field.

The C standard guarantees that the address of the structure is always aligned to the address of the first element (i.e. there is no padding before the first structure member). So it's safe to first cast `void*` to the type field and, depending on that outcome, cast to the structure of your choice.

Comment: thumbs up for guessing I will type cast later :)